# Javascript Concat Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to concat a multidimensional array so I can iterate and display all the data.  There is a very good post on how to access nested data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json), but I am looking for a solution that works with a specific data structure.

Here is my data:

```
var data = {
"Nike": [
    {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "test",
    "myimage": "image.gif"},

     {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test",
    "myimage": "image.gif"}
],

"Adidas": [
    {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Football Boots",
    "myimage": "image.gif"},

     {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Running Shoes",
    "myimage": "image.gif"}
]}
```

I seem to be able to get the values from the Nike array if I do this:

```
var result = data.Adidas;


for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
 var object = result[i];
 for (property in object) {
    var value = object[property];
    alert(property + "=" + value + "<br>");
 }
}
```

However I would like to be able to display all the array items (id's 1-4).

What I have tried to do is:

```
var result = [].concat.apply([], data);
```

... and loop over the result variable using the same for loop, but it doesn't work.

My ideal end result would be to display the four products under each brand name. I don't require to show the actual brand name itself.  For example:

```
 "id": "1",
    "name": "test",
    "myimage": "image.gif"

 "id": "2",
    "name": "test",
    "myimage": "image.gif"

"id": "3",
    "name": "Football Boots",
    "myimage": "image.gif",

"id": "4",
    "name": "Running Shoes",
    "myimage": "image.gif"
```

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and iterate over the keys of the object, then create your array:

```
var mashed = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(arr, key) {
    return arr.concat(data[key]);
}, []);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kvd6egn5/

Comment: Perfect!! Does exactly what I am looking for.  Thanks so much tymeJV

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to reduce would be a `for in` loop:

```
let res = [];
for (let key in data) res = res.concat(data[key]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lodash mergeWith function:

```
const object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};

const other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith