# Need to concat arrays( don't know how much would be) (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example view of my arr.

[image]

There need to concat deepest objects,

for example have 2 arrays `[{id1:color:grey}] [{id4:color:grey},{id8:color:grey}]`

in result need be this: `[{id1:color:grey},{id4:color:grey},{id8:color:grey}]`

try do something this but no idea how to concat, I don't know how much arrays can be

```
var kkk = [];

        for (var i=0; i < arrData.length;i++) {
          var his = arrData[i][1];
          for(var k=0; k < his.length; k++) {
            console.log(his[0])
          }

        }
```

what I must do in loop? and loop is correct?

My object :

```
Array[2]
0:"th"
1:Array[2]
   0:Array[1] //this need concat
   1:Array[1] //this need concat

["th"
,[[[{"id":4,"color":"grey"},
{"id":5,"color":"grey"},
{"id":6,"color":"grey"},
{"id":7,"color":"grey"},
{"id":8,"color":"grey"},
{"id":9,"color":"grey"},
{"id":10,"color":"grey"},
{"id":11,"color":"grey"},{"id":12,"color":"grey"}]],

[[{"id":19,"color":"grey"},{"id":20,"color":"grey"},{"id":21,"color":"grey"}

]]]]
```

Comment: Please share your object

Comment: you have nothing like `[{id1:color:grey}] [{id4:color:grey},{id8:color:grey}]` because that simply isn't valid - and when someone says "share your object" that doesn't mean a picture of it :p

Comment: *Need to concat arrays*, you should look into `Array.concat`.

Comment: @Rajesh how to concat, if I don't now how much will be?

Comment: @HassanImam added

Comment: Please `JSON.stringify()` your object and update the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Concat Multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971357/javascript-concat-multidimensional-array)

Comment: This operation is called "flatten". You should be able to search for "flatten" implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the array and then concatenate results into the array.

I used code from [one](https://github.com/imbhargav5/just-flatten-array/blob/master/src/index.js) of my repos.

```js
var arr = [[[{color : "red", id : 1}]],[{color : "green", id : 2}],[[[{color : "yellow", id : 3}]]],[{color : "blue", id : 4}]];

const __flattenReducer = (result,value,valueIndex,arr)=>{
  if(value instanceof Array){
    return value.reduce(__flattenReducer,result);
  }else{
    result.push(value);
    return result;
  }
};

const flatten = function(arr){
   if(arr instanceof Array){
     return Array.prototype.reduce.apply(arr,[__flattenReducer,[]]);
   }else{
     throw new TypeError('Expected an array');
   }
}

console.log(flatten(arr))
```

Comment: Repeated pushing onto an array will be much less performant than Array.prototype.concat

Answer (score 0):

```
function flatten(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) return 
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr.map(flatten));
  return arr;
}
```

This is the basic recursive solution for flatten.